# How to speed up append to an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append or add rows to the existing dataframe which has around 7 million rows.

Now the challenge I am facing is I am able to do the same using `iterrows` in the following manner:

```
for key,value in df.iterrows():
                if value['col3'] > 0:
                    df.loc[len(df),['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']] = [value['col1']+value['col3'],value['col2'],value['col3'],value['col4'],'blah']
```

and using `itertuples` in following manner:

```
for tup in df.itertuples(index = False):
                if tup[4] > 0:
                    df.loc[len(df),['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']] = [tup[1]+ tup[3],tup[2], tup[3],tup[4],'blah']
```

Both of these do the job, but it is hitting on processing time.

Can someone please suggest me a better way to do this in Python pandas?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here, appending rows is highly non-performant as it needs to grow and probably copy the contents periodically, for instance in your first loop all you're doing is copying all the row values down except for col3 where you're adding col1.

Comment: @EdChum What i want to achieve here is that i have a start time converted to epoch and time spent on application in seconds, which is needs to be added to give me 2 rows one with start time of application use and stop time of application use. 
The reason i do this is, there might be click events between the start and stop times which i want to capture to process the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking), if you need append rows by conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

#original data
temp=u"""col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,2,3,4,5
3,4,-5,6,7
5,6,-7,8,9"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
print df1
#   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#0     1     2     3     4     5
#1     3     4    -5     6     7
#2     5     6    -7     8     9

#copy data for next processing
df = df1.copy()

#set data by conditions
df1['col1'] = np.where(df1['col3'] > 0,  df1['col1'] + df1['col3'], np.NaN)
df1['col5'] = np.where(df1['col3'] > 0,  'blah', np.NaN)

#drop rows with NaN
df1 = df1.dropna()

#append to original df
result = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
print result
#   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#0     1     2     3     4     5
#1     3     4    -5     6     7
#2     5     6    -7     8     9
#3     4     2     3     4  blah
```

Comment: the solution provided is awesome when it comes to modifying the dataframe, the question here is i have to grow the dataframe, to achieve what is required.
The problem i have is 
i have a start time converted to epoch and time spent on application in seconds, which is needs to be added to give me 2 rows one with start time of application use and stop time of application use. The reason i do this is,  there are click events between the start and stop times which i want to capture to process the data

Comment: Thanks @jezrael this worked like a gem, but i am still curious, if rather than just copying this to a new dataframe and performing operations on the same, could we have a better solution. This works awesomely well with smaller datasets, but with larger dataframes like have 10 million entries in each dataframe would hit my computations resources.